# Need text to go below bottom nav bar

Tags: html

The bottom of my page is supposed to have contact information below the bottom navigation bar. For some reason I cannot get this to happen. The contact info goes up above the bottom navigation even though the code has it below.

```
<footer>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Bio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Career</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Links</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br />
  <div id="contactinfo">Twin Artesian Stables
    <br />2990 Oakdale Dr.,
    <br />Suamico, WI
    <br />920-865-5555
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ptopyyLw/ ..i think its showing correct as you are expecting ? whats wrong ?

Comment: It might be a CSS problem. What rules are associated with #contactinfo in your style?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if there is positions set in your css for #nav #contactinfo -> has to be

```
#nav #contactinfo{position:relative}...
```